# Splitting royalties from NFT sales to NFT holders using opensea

Tags: nft, erc-1155, opensea, royalties

I have a smart contract for NFT airdrop and whitelisting written in erc 1155
I've been researching for about a week and couldn't find an answer since OpenSea does not enforce EIP 2981 yet
I have implemented the function for future proofing but for now how can I send royalties from opensea to NFT hodlers
I thought of writing another smart contract and sending the royalties from OS then splitting them to the NFT holders? I'd have to validate who minted the original one so they receive royalties and implement a function that allows withdrawals after its actually profitable after gas fees
anyone ever write something similar or any famous NFTs whos architecture I could check out?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71513603/can-not-set-opensea-io-royalties-on-a-nft-contract.

Comment: The issue is that I know they send them once a month
but they send it to one address, not split them as shares to the different NFT holders

Comment: You should contact OpenSea customer support, they have the information. If the operations were on-chain you could index them and determine the fees paid.

Comment: has anyone managed to find a fix?